# Convert base64 to image and display on browser only

Tags: javascript, captcha, simplecaptcha

I know that this question has already been asked but there's not a single solution for my case. I am generating a Captcha using JavaScript of three letters and I am able to convert them to base64 string so as to able to convert it further to an image file and display on the browser. I am not able to convert the base64 format to image format. I can use the Google reCaptcha but I am doing this for learning purpose. So any help would be great!
This is my JavaScript code:

```
var code2 = ''
$('#captCha').ready(function Captcha() {
    var alpha = new Array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z')

    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        var a = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)]
        var b = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)]
        var c = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)]
    }
    var code = a + ' ' + b + ' ' + ' ' + c

    code2 = removeSpaces(code)
    var b64 = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(code2)))
    console.log(b64)
    document.getElementById('captCha').innerHTML = b64
});

function removeSpaces (string) {
    return string.split(' ').join('')
}
```

Comment: So, you want to convert a ___string___ to a ___image___?

Comment: are you trying to display your image on an <img> tag?

Comment: I hope you realize that a base64 encoded string is something __completely different__ than a base64 encoded image... The encoding is just a way to represent the binary data. Using the same encoding for two _different_ things doesn't suddenly make the two interchangeable.

Comment: @Cerbrus...I read somewhere that a base64 can be converted to an image.

Comment: @MeghaVerma: Assuming it is a base64 representation of a _image_. Base64 is just like morse code: It's a way of encoding data. If you encode a text to morse code, you can't decode it into anything but text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could draw the text on a `canvas` element and then get the base64-encoded image from the canvas:

```js
const alpha = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 
               'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 
               'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
               'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];

const a = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
const b = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
const c = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
const code = a + ' ' + b + ' ' + c;

const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.font = '24px sans-serif';
context.fillText(code, 10, 50);

const img = document.createElement('img');
img.setAttribute('src', canvas.toDataURL());

document.body.appendChild(img);
```

Comment: Wow!! It worked magically for me. Thank you so much!!